# What are the softwares or drivers needed to establish database connectivity using JDBC-ODBC driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I have Oracle 10g and NetBeans 6v and Apache Tomcat server is that enough to connect to database? Is there any need to have MS SQL server compulserely?
Please give me some suggestions..

Comment: 1.) Why would you want to use the JDBC-ODBC bridge? Don't use it, unless it's **absolutely** necessary. 2.) Why should you need MS SQL Server to connect to an Oracle DB? That doesn't even begin to make sense!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you need is Oracle JDBC driver. It is downloadable from Oracle.com.

[Oracle JDBC driver.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)
To tell the truth you only need Java, Oracle JDBC driver and Oracle DB itself. You need Tomcat only if you wish to create web application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the **Oracle ODBC Driver** installed. It's generally found in the [Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html).

Do note that the JDBC-ODBC bridge is only intended for [testing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/bridge.doc.html)! See this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) also!

Comment: @Joachim: Deepa said he wanted to use the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver. That's included with Java but requires an ODBC driver as well. That's in ODAC.

Answer (score 0):

With the JDBC-ODBC driver you need to setup the ODBC to the database you want to use. For Oracle, you will need the Oracle ODBC Driver for the host (not the java version).

Usually it is simpler to just use the Java Driver for the database, if available (never has put a link to it), directly from the java program/framework.